# Modularize credentials in legacy JSP project

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, legacy

I'm trying to modularize credentials disparate among several (dozens) JSP files (exploded war in Tomcat 6). I've found I can't create a single JSP (e.g. that would read a single credentials file) and then import it because imported code may get duplicated, causing errors (I've found there's nothing similar to C's #ifdef/ifndef directives in JSP). Are there other ways to refactor this project? I think credentials shouldn't be managed this way, but in the short term, I can't just migrate the whole project because of its size.

An oversimplified example:

```
// createConnection.jsp

String user = "the user";
String password = "the password";

conn = openJdbcConnection(user, password, etc);
return conn;
```

`createConnection.jsp` gets imported into several other JSPs and the returned `conn` is used to query data.

Plus, there're other variants of `createConnection.jsp` which have their own copy/implementation of `openJdbcConnection`.

My first attempt was to isolate the code and try to import it where it's currently used, but some JSP already import other JSP which already has code like this (imagine importing `createConnection.jsp` into `connectionCreator.jsp` or a JSP having API-like routines to query data which in turn get imported into other files).

The main issue is credentials are all over the place and changing them is difficult and error-prone.

Comment: It's very difficult to tell from this what your issue really is.  Can you share some code to describe the problem a bit better?

Comment: I would use an ordinary Java class that you call from the JSPs, rather than putting the code into a JSP that is imported into the other ones. In general, it is now considered best practice to minimize the amount of Java code in a JSP and to restrict it as much as possible to UI logic.